# NGINX Too Many Redirects

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, centos8

I'm doing a proxy server with NGINX to redirect all traffic from port 80 to port 443 and then all traffic from port 443 to an app in one of my servers. I managed to make it work but only redirecting to my main IP 192.168.1.201:8006. When I try to point to my app (192.168.1.201:8006/customerSite/)the page gives me the error TOO MANY REDIRECTS.

Here is my .conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This is my ssl.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /.../certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /.../clientsmydomain.key;
    
    large_client_header_buffers 4 10k;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    
    ssl protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    
    ssl_trusted_certificate /.../certificate.crt;
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.201:8060;
    }
    
    location /weights {
        root /var/www/virtual/server;
        try_files $URI $uri/ = 404;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by `point to my app`? What exactly `Location` HTTP header an occurred redirection returns?

Comment: I mean redirect to a specified module (customerSite) in my server. Maybe I expressed myself wrong. The redirection returns the HTTP header "myDomain.com", which I have no problem with. The problem comes when I try to redirect to myDomain.com/customerSite/